# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[...] can't be used even after including "using System.Configuration"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm coding a project in C# in ASP.net MVC. I have the connection string in the Web.config file. I can't share it due to security reasons. In my code, I have the line: `string CS2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."].ConnectionString;` But I get an error and a red line under "ConfigurationManager" that says it does not exist in the current context.

I've checked other pages that say I need to include the reference by clicking on the project > Add > Reference > and then select the correct one. But I don't see Configuration listed there. And after browsing and searching, I still don't find it. I'm not quite sure what I can do besides try learning the Entity Framework which I'm not really a fan of doing.

EDIT: solution ended up being finding the library in NuGet, installing it, and adding an app.config file with the connectionString in it.

Answer (score 0):

What version of .NET are you using? For .NET Core projects, reference the Nuget package linked below. For a full .NET project you should be able to include the `System.Configuration` project from references. And make sure `using System.Configuration;` is in place.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/

Comment: I'm using .NET Core 2.1 I think. I'm not sure how to check MVC version so I wasn't able to add it to the question. I do have ```using System.Configuration``` at the top of the Controller, but it is listed as unnecessary.

Comment: @KurtisHonk-KurtChow: Find out. Your question says *"ASP.net MVC"* which is how the .NET Framework (non-Core) MVC implementation is branded (tag: [tag:asp.net-mvc]). It means something specific. There's a separate tag for MVC in ASP.NET Core, which is [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]. However, this question isn't related to either implementation of MVC because System.Configuration isn't limited ASP.NET, so what matters is .NET Framework vs. .NET Core. Do you have Program.cs and Startup.cs in the root of the project?

Comment: I have both. But I was able to figure out a solution from your earlier solution. I looked into the NuGet Package manager and found the ConfigurationManager in there. Installed it and added an apps.config file and it started working. Though I'm not sure if this would be considered good code(in regards to having both an app.config and web.config in a ASP.net MVC project).

Comment: Web.config isn't used by ASP.NET Core. It's used by IIS to configure the module that acts as the reverse proxy in the deployed environment. If you have a web.config that has configuration, it's probably just a remnant of the pre-upgraded project.